# How to change a link with theme_preprocess_page

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I have a content type called type1 and this content type has an image field called image1. I want to change image1's link url to something. How can I do this with heme_preprocess_page or any other method.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are 100+ methods.
Try hook_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode){}